# Dynamicly resizeable custom Buttons - how to make?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, unity3d-2dtools

please I have bought GUI pack for 2D mobile games. I have vectors for buttons but I don't know how to make it "smaller" - dynamically resizable for Unity.

This is my bought button:[image]

And I need to make from it this (with all corners, etc.)

[image]

In Unity, I will resize it according to my needs and add text. But I don't know how to make it in Photoshop or Illustrator, how to smaller it with keep corners and make "middle" of button to be dynamic.

Comment: Since your question is about how to edit an image in Photoshop, I suggest that this would be a better place for it: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use the "Image Type" property on your Sprite component.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html

That option gives you the possibility of scaling the center of the image, keeping the size of the borders.

In this video they explain the property (from 1:16 aprox)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFQcc1GUe7U

Cheers !